# Lint for Swift in Xcode

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, lint, swiftlint

I found SwiftLint included it in my podfile and did a pod install.

I cannot find where to invoke it in my build phases.
I would be grateful for pointers and maybe a line or two of clarification.

Answer (score 1):

See [the documentation](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint#xcode), which tells you how to add the “Run Script” phase.

So, in short, when adding SwiftLint via CocoaPods, go to your target settings, “build phases”, tap on `+` button, add run script, and use this for the script:

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/SwiftLint/swiftlint"
```

Comment: Not working for me "${PODS_ROOT}/SwiftLint/swiftlint" Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code